# show grants for someuser not working for root

Tags: mariadb

I have two servers both running on Version(): **10.3.21-MariaDB**

On server1 when I log into mysql as root and execute the command: `show grants for someuser;` It shows me all the grants for that user.

On server2 when I log into mysql as root and execute the command: `show grants for someuser;` I get this error:

> ERROR 1141 (42000): There is no such grant defined for user 'someuser'
>   on host '%'

On both servers when I execute the command:

```
select user from mysql.user;
```

I get a list of the users. So the users that I am trying to see their grants are there ...

What is would be different with server2 that root can not see the grants ?

on all the servers is_role = N

but I did notice another difference among the 3 servers - the root user has different host entries 
Also I have added the vm type that the server is running
also have results for a 3rd server

server3 (virtuozzo)
show grant must have the @somehost
using all of the different host entries give a result with the only difference being the @somehost is whatever was used in the for someuser@somehost

GRANT USAGE ON *.* TO 'someuser'@'somehost'  indentified by ....
GRANT USAGE ON *.* TO 'someuser'@'ip address'  indentified by ...
etc.

root user entries:
| root      | localhost             | N       |
| root      | server.example.com    | N       |
| root      | 127.0.0.1             | N       |
| root      | ::1                   | N       |

server2 (vmware)
show grant must have the @host
only the @ip address gives a result

root user entries:
| root                | localhost             | N       |
| mysql.session       | localhost             | N       | 
| mysql.sys           | localhost             | N       |

server1 (kwm)
show grant does not have to have the @host
using all of the different host entries give a result with the only difference being the @somehost is whatever was used in the for someuser@somehost

GRANT USAGE ON *.* TO 'someuser'@'somehost'  indentified by ....
GRANT USAGE ON *.* TO 'someuser'@'ip address'  indentified by ...
etc.

root user entries:
| root               | localhost                         | N       |
| root               | cent6base-cpanel.pxe.bluehost.com | N       |
| root               | 127.0.0.1                         | N

Comment: check this: https://mariadb.com/kb/en/error-1141-42000-there-is-no-such-grant-defined-for-user/

Answer (score 1):

I'm only guessing here, but could it be that you have defined different `host` values for `someuser` on server1 and server2?

When you execute `SHOW GRANTS FOR someuser;` it really executes `SHOW GRANTS FOR someuser@'%';` - that is, if you don't specify the host part, the it will default to using the wildcard (`%`) for the host part.

So if you have `someuser@'%'` on server1 and e.g. `someuser@'localhost'` on server2, then you will get the result you have observed.

You can see the host part of the users by executing `SELECT user, host FROM mysql.user;`

And then you can view the grants for the different users by executing `SHOW GRANTS FOR someuser@'localhost';` or similar for users with other host values in their `mysql.user` rows. Note that each row in the table is a different user - it doesn't matter that some of them might have the same user names as long as they have different host values.

Comment: So I did the select user, host from mysql.user; and it listed the users for several hosts: someuser | xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx, someuser | localhost, someuser | server.mydomain.org, -  on server 2 only the command: show hosts for someuser@xxx.xxx.xxx.xxxx showed me the grants for someuser .... whereas on server1  they all show the grants.  I set up the users on both servers exactly the same way (via cpanel) - and only server2 requires the someuser@host to show the grants ... and  only when I referenced the server ip

Comment: @pineyscripter Does the `SELECT user, host FROM mysql.user;` query give you the same result on server1 and server2?

Comment: Also, you might want to try `SELECT user, host, is_role FROM mysql.user;` on both servers and make sure you get the same result.

Comment: on all the servers is_role = N

but I did notice another difference among the 3 servers - the root user has different host entries 
Also I have added the vm type that the server is running
also have results for a 3rd server

Comment: @pineyscripter Do you have a user someuser@'%' on server1? If so, that would explain why you are able to do `SHOW GRANTS FOR someuser;` on that server. When you do `SHOW GRANTS FOR ...` you really should include the host. The user + host are the two components that together uniquely identify a DB user. If you leave out the host, then MariaDB will assume you actually mean `'%'`. I hope that explains it.